# How do I keep the KMLTreeView item 'selected' when the TreeView loses focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview, google-earth-plugin

In Google Earth the background color of a selected item in the KMLTreeView dims when clicking on the Globe.  In my C# based application the TreeView Node loses all color so I do not know which item is selected.

Similarly, I would like to have the treeview node highlight when I click on its associated placemark as also happens in GE.

I assume this is the default behavior so I must not be associating the placemarks with the kmltreeview properly.  Below is the code I use for creating and adding the node to the globe as well as the kmltreeview control.  Is there something I'm doing wrong or not doing to be able to use the default behavior?

Thanks!

```
dynamic placemark = KmlHelpers.CreatePlacemark(ge1,
                                               Coord,
                                               d.sSerialNumber,
                                               d.sNickname,
                                               "Device Type: " + d.sName + "<p>" +
                                               "IP Address: " + d.sIPAddress + "<p>" +
                                               "ESN: " + d.sSerialNumber + "<p>" +
                                               "<a href=\"http://localhost/index.html#"
                                               + d.sSerialNumber + "\">Details</a>");

var styleMap = ge1.createStyleMap("");

// Create normal style for style map.
var normalStyle = ge1.createStyle("");
var normalIcon = ge1.createIcon("");
normalIcon.setHref("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/truck.png");
normalStyle.getIconStyle().setIcon(normalIcon);

// Create highlight style for style map.
var highlightStyle = ge1.createStyle("");
var highlightIcon = ge1.createIcon("");
highlightIcon.setHref("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/truck.png");
highlightStyle.getIconStyle().setIcon(highlightIcon);
highlightStyle.getIconStyle().setScale(2.0);
styleMap.setNormalStyle(normalStyle);
styleMap.setHighlightStyle(highlightStyle);

// Apply stylemap to a placemark.
placemark.setStyleSelector(styleMap);

kmlTreeView.ParseKmlObject(placemark);
```

Comment: Just to note, I develop the library you are using. I may well make this the default behaviour for the KmlTreeView control. Could you possibly put it in a request ticket here? http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/issues/entry?template=Enhancement%20report%20from%20user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [KmlTreeView](http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/wiki/KmlTreeView) inherits from the standard [TreeView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch6etkw4.aspx), as such you can use the [HideSelection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.hideselection.aspx) property. By default this is set to `True`, however...

> When this property is set to false, selected nodes in the TreeView
>   control remain highlighted in a different color than the current
>   selection color when the TreeView control loses focus. You can use
>   this property to keep items that are selected by the user visible when
>   the user clicks a different control on the form or moves to a
>   different window.

To do this in code, for example:

```
kmlTreeView.HideSelection = False;
```

Also, the property can be set in the visual designer for the control, simply select the KmlTreeView, then view the properties. Finally, double click on `HideSelection` to set it to `False`

**UPDATE:**

For the second part of the question, highlighting a node when the coorisponding feature is clicked, you would need to write a custom event handler and then use the KmlTreeView's `GetNodeById` method. Some thing like the following should work.

```
private void GEWebBrowser1OnPluginReady(object sender, GEEventArgs geEventArgs)
{
    this.geWebBrowser1.AddEventListener(geEventArgs.ApiObject.getGlobe(), EventId.MouseDown);
    this.geWebBrowser1.KmlEvent += geWebBrowser1_KmlEvent;
}

void geWebBrowser1_KmlEvent(object sender, GEEventArgs e)
{
    // the feature that the mousedown event fired on
    dynamic feature = e.ApiObject.getTarget();

    // If you have other events added you will need some conditional logic here
    // to sort out which event has fired. e.g.
    // if(e.EventId == EventId.MouseDown)
    // if(GEHelpers.IsApiType(feature, ApiType.KmlPlacemark);
    // etc..

    string id = feature.getId(); // the features id
    KmlTreeViewNode node = myKmlTreeView.GetNodeById(id);   // find the corresponding node...    
    if(node == null) { return; } // no corresponding node...

    // set the selected node to the feature node.
    myKmlTreeView.SelectedNode = node; 

    // make sure the node is visible in the treeview
    if (!node.IsVisible)
    {
        node.EnsureVisible();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fraser.  I found the property in the visual designer and forgot to come back and update this question.  It takes care of the first part but not the second.  If I click on a placemark in the gebrowser it does not highlight the corresponding kmltreeview node.  Any thoughts about that one?

Comment: Sure, it is simply a case of using the features ID. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Outstanding - I'll give it a go shortly.  I submitted the request ticket you asked for.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hi Fraser,  two questions.
    1) The AddEventListener line did not work.  I changed it to the following:               

    geWebBrowser1.AddEventListener(ge1.getGlobe(), EventId.MouseDown);
    Is there something I'm doing wrong?
    2) The GetNodeByApiId is not in my library.  I searched the xml documentation and did not see it in there either.
    Do I have an old library? (v9.0.8112.16455)

Comment: I just pulled down the build from 11/20 and it has the same behavior.

Comment: Ah, my bad - the method name is GetNodeById and the AddEventListener call should take an EventID. I have edited the example, sorry about that. Also, you should put the AddEventListener call within your  `GEWebBrowserOnPluginReady` handler - or at least make sure it isn't called until the plugin has finished loading...Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Fraser, that was perfect thanks!  The dimmed color is a very light grey - can I change it?

Comment: Great...as for the colour change, no, not easily at all... However the version I am about to commit handles all this for you. It leaves the node highlighted in the System.Highlight colour (default is a mid-blue). The behaviour will controlled via a new `KmlTreeView.HideSelectedNodeOnBlur` property and it will default to `False` so that the functionality you outlined will be the default behaviour for the control. I plan to commit later this evening :)

Comment: Hi Fraser,  I've run into a bit of a snag.  After adding a second treeview the SelectedNode functionality has stopped working.  I'm implementing my own mouse over and mouse down functions to do the highlighting and unhighlighting manually because I need to get it done today but if you have any thoughts on why it might have stopped working please let me know.  Thanks.

Comment: Really hard to day without seeing the actual code...Rather than continuing here can we move the discussion to the feature request you created? http://code.google.com/p/winforms-geplugin-control-library/issues/detail?id=98 - also, I will have a play myself and see if I can ascertain what the issue could be.